# Does allowing bets between people require a gambling licence?

Tags: business, gambling

1. Suppose that an app allows users to make bets among themselves. Based on the outcome being bet on, the winning party will receive payment from the losing party. Is this legal? Would this require a gambling licence?
2. If not, what are some things that would make it require a gambling licence?

Comment: Jurisdiction? Many states have no such thing as a gambling license, those that do will have specific rules.

Comment: @DaleM what exactly do you mean by jurisdiction?

Comment: If you are asking questions on a law site then you *really* need to look up the meaning of jurisdiction

Comment: @DaleM Like are you asking where the servers would be located? Or where I would be managing said app? Those have the potential to be 2 completely different locations. i.e. I would be in Wisconsin while the servers that host/ run it could be in Sweden.

Comment: Yes and also where the users are - you will have multiple jurisdictions to deal with.

Comment: That makes it exponentially complex since potentially anyone in the world could uses it.

Comment: Yes, welcome to the internet

Comment: Apart from jurisdiction, it is also unclear what you mean by "allow". MS Word "allows" you to make bets, in that it has no way to hinder you. Do you mean that the program actively facilitates betting: in what way?

Comment: Some games do this, in fact, Tether Studios has multiple games in the App Store using this concept. You might be able to contact and ask them here: http://www.tetherstudios.com/welcome/about_us